# How to convert an ASCII string into a decimal number?

Tags: c

I am trying to convert an ASCII string into a decimal number, but it doesn’t work
I tried this way.

```
char tab[4] = {53,70,51,68};
int a = (int)strtol(tab, NULL, 16);
printf("a = %d",a);
```

as input i have 53,70,51,68 => in hex 5F3D
as output i should got => 24381

Comment: To improve readabilty **a lot** please use character constants: `char tab[4] = {'5','F','3','D'};` or even better a valid string: `char tab[5] = "5F3D";` This must include the mandatory nul-termination for your string which is missing in your code. Feeding anything else than a properly nul-terminated string into `strtol` is causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: "it doesn’t work" How so? What's your output?

Comment: `tab` need to be NULL terminated to be a valid C string.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Or even better: Provide a string: `char tab[] = "5f3d"`. This way, your string will be null terminated without needing to provide an extra '\0'.

Comment: As has been pointed out, your problem is likely caused by the missing null character needed to terminate the string passed to `strtol`. However, you have not given the information required to diagnose a problem. Questions like this should always include a [mre]. That includes a complete runnable program, the output produced, and the output expected instead.

Comment: @pqans My example contains the nul termination. A string literal always includes that. As my array size `[5]` provides enough space, there is no difference between your result and mine. You only left out the size for convenience.

Comment: I see that but i would still avoid hardcoded array size if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your char array is missing the NUL terminator (`0 == 0x00 == '\0'`).

```
const char tab[5] = {53, 70, 51, 68, 0};
               
int a = (int) strtol(tab, NULL, 16);

printf("number: %d\n", a);
```

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

It might work if it is missing, but this is undefined behavior, see comments below.

Comment: Fixed it, but then I've got a question: It worked for me without terminator, might this have worked because a random zero came after the array?

Comment: @earthling "undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine". And yes, probably there was a zero right after the array, but it could be as well any other value.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you... :)

Comment: Actually not only `'\0'` (NUL) but any value different from `'0'` to `'9'` and different from `'A'` to `'F'` will be considered as a terminator by `strtol`, so the chances are high that it appears to work if the string is not NUL terminated.